# Conda vs pip solving complex dependency trees

Tags: anaconda, conda

I remember `conda` solver was more robust / produced more correct results when I was creating fairly complex environments with up to a hundred of dependencies.

Has the `pip` solver improved over the years? I don't have a good example handy, but from what I remember if there are

- transient dependencies coming from package A
- conflicting with transient dependencies packages coming from B

(simplified example), `pip` didn't do a good job, vs `conda` always produced correctly solved environments.

Are there any (documented or not documented) examples when `pip` solver falls short? Eg. like in the example above.

ps. With the recent licensing changes coming from Anaconda, Inc. I have a customer that's considering to standardize on `pip` and forgo `conda`.

Comment: Have a read through [pip needs a dependency resolver #988](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) (long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip doesn't do a good job at resolving transient dependencies.

pip's dependency resolution algorithm is not a complete resolver.

> The current resolution logic has the following characteristics:
>
> - Only one top level specification of a requirement (otherwise pip raises a "double requirement" exception) "- first found wins" behavior
>   for dependency requirements/constraints, which results in not
>   respecting all constraints. pip 10+ print a warning when this occurs.

Discussed [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988)

pip has been trying to solve this for a long time, and the new pip 20.3 has implemented a [new solver](https://blog.python.org/2020/11/pip-20-3-release-new-resolver.html) that should address this, but [still has its own issues](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9187).